# action script 3.0 resizing an image as animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want after clicking on button mini1 pic1 to go to the center of page and change the size... This code works fine but I would like to change the size and position dynamically... Can I change this code somehow to achieve the effect of resizing the image or I have to do this by motion tweens...?

```
mini1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, show1);

function show1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    pic1.visible = true;

    if (pic1.y > 440) {
        pic1.y -= 270;
        pic1.x = 300;
        pic1.width = 400;
        pic1.height = 400;
    }

    pic2.visible = false;
    pic3.visible = false;
    pic4.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: If you want to animate this with code, you'll have to use a tween package. Have you checked out [GreenSock](http://www.greensock.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pic1.width = 400;
pic1.height = 400;
pic1.x = stage.stageWidth-pic1.width;
pic1.y = stage.stageHeight-pic1.height;
```

Plase note that the *x* and *y* property need to change just after you resize the image

Comment: You can use relative referencing to stageHeight and stageWidth to find the center of the screen, too.

This should center your image horizontally:
`pic1.x = (stage.stageWidth/2)-(pic1.width/2);`

It locates the image's anchor at the center of screen, minus half of the image's width. This will work if your anchor is at (0,0).